# Using animate.css (link in description) how do I trigger an animation when a particular event is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an an image moving across the screen and out of viewport, when the image reaches a particular absolute position (right: - 200), I want to trigger the below animation. I am relatively new to programming, not sure how to track when a particular function is done so that I can trigger the below animation.

```
var $startLessonButton = $('.startLessonButtonUp');

$startLessonButton.mouseup(function() {
 $(this).addClass('animated slideInLeft');
});

---------

var movingOutAnimationCounter = 2;
var movingOutCurrentPosition = window.innerWidth / 2 - 200

function moveTrumpOut() {
    movingOutCurrentPosition -= 2;
    trumpyWrapper.style.right = movingOutCurrentPosition + 'px';
    if (movingOutAnimationCounter < 9 ) {
        trumpy.src = '../images/trump_walking_out_' + movingOutAnimationCounter + '.png';
        movingOutAnimationCounter += 1;
    } else {
        movingOutAnimationCounter = 1;
        trumpy.src = '../images/trump_walking_out_' + movingOutAnimationCounter + '.png';
    }
    if (movingOutCurrentPosition > -200 ) {
        requestAnimationFrame(moveTrumpOut);
    }
}
```

All the best!

Comment: Using this css library: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Answer (score 0):

If you know time, when moving element is hidden, you can use this function:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('.elem').addClass("animCssClass") }, 1000);
```

Last parameter, in this example: 1000 is time in ms, when function inside should execute. Run this function on `mouseup` when you adding class to moving element.